# Assign a JVM in a multiple JVM application for a process through code

Tags: jvm

I have a application in which there are 2 server each having 2 JVMs each. There is one process (say X) in the application which is very huge and consumes lot of memory for execution. If any user lands on the same JVM as where the process X is running, the application UI is slowed down drastically for the user.

Is there a way I can assign 2 of the 4 JVMs to run for process X through the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to tell us more about your setup. Are you using any framework for task distribution/load balancing? Those will have support for scheduling according to resource availability.

Comment: Any one JVM can use all the resources of the server so if a machine is busy you need to redirect users to the other machine.

Comment: Round robin load balancing mechanism has been used.
@PeterLawrey can you be a bit clear?

Comment: @Sravanthi round Robin won't help if you have only two machines and one can be busy. You either have to make sure the load is even enough or you have to distribute work based on load.